# LanguageLocaleKey On User Object, difference in codes!

Tags: integration, languagelocalekey

I have integrated Salesforce with external system, in external system LanguageLocaleKey  codes are stored like "ar_DZ","ca_ES" etc. however when I am trying to send values of LanguageLocaleKey  to external system from Salesforce(Field on User Object), these codes aren't getting passed through validation of languages except for English,

If Language of User selected at Salesforce side is English the code will be sent like "en_US" which is valid for external system.

However if I select French as a Language, code will be sent like "Fr" why this is the case for other languages, because when I check the documentation here [Supported Locales](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=0) I can see that codes are like "ar_DZ","ca_ES" etc, but when I am retrieving the value of LanguageLocaleKey  from database it will return me like "ar" ,"ca".

I wanted to understand why it is a special case for English that code gets form like "en_US" and not for other languages.

e.g On User I am selecting Language as Espanol 
[image]

When I will query the LanguageLocaleKey value from database it will return me code like "es" however for English it will give me code "en_Us"
[image]

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that these are older users? There used to only be a single es (Spanish), instead of the half-dozen or so we have today. Once you update the users' languages, you should get the values you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a deeper look into language setting,

1. I checked Language Settings
   [image: Language Settings]

When I enabled it, I observed that it enabled platform-only languages, and when I debug result using code provided by @Adrian in his answer I got the result like following:

```
{"es_VE":"Spanish (Venezuela)","es_UY":"Spanish (Uruguay)","es_US":"Spanish (United States)","es_PR":"Spanish (Puerto Rico)","es_PE":"Spanish (Peru)","es_PY":"Spanish (Paraguay)","es_PA":"Spanish (Panama)","es_NI":"Spanish (Nicaragua)","es_HN":"Spanish (Honduras)","es_GT":"Spanish (Guatemala)","es_SV":"Spanish (El Salvador)","es_EC":"Spanish (Ecuador)","es_DO":"Spanish (Dominican Republic)","es_CR":"Spanish (Costa Rica)","es_CO":"Spanish (Colombia)","es_CL":"Spanish (Chile)","es_BO":"Spanish (Bolivia)","es_AR":"Spanish (Argentina)","it_CH":"Italian (Switzerland)","de_LU":"German (Luxembourg)","fr_CH":"French (Switzerland)","fr_LU":"French (Luxembourg)","fr_BE":"French (Belgium)","en_ZA":"English (South Africa)","en_SG":"English (Singapore)","en_IE":"English (Ireland)","en_HK":"English (Hong Kong)","zh_HK":"Chinese (Hong Kong)","zh_SG":"Chinese (Singapore)","ar_YE":"Arabic (Yemen)","ar_AE":"Arabic (United Arab Emirates)","ar_TN":"Arabic (Tunisia)","ar_SY":"Arabic (Syria)","ar_SD":"Arabic (Sudan)","ar_SA":"Arabic (Saudi Arabia)","ar_QA":"Arabic (Qatar)","ar_OM":"Arabic (Oman)","ar_MA":"Arabic (Morocco)","ar_LY":"Arabic (Libya)","ar_LB":"Arabic (Lebanon)","ar_KW":"Arabic (Kuwait)","ar_JO":"Arabic (Jordan)","ar_IQ":"Arabic (Iraq)","ar_EG":"Arabic (Egypt)","ar_BH":"Arabic (Bahrain)","ar_DZ":"Arabic (Algeria)","ta":"Tamil","de_CH":"German (Switzerland)","de_AT":"German (Austria)","bn":"Bengali","ur":"Urdu","hi":"Hindi","hy":"Armenian","rm":"Romansh","lb":"Luxembourgish","tl":"Tagalog","ms":"Malay","is":"Icelandic","cy":"Welsh","eu":"Basque","ga":"Irish","mt":"Maltese","sh_ME":"Montenegrin","sq":"Albanian","et":"Estonian","lt":"Lithuanian","lv":"Latvian","mk":"Macedonian","bs":"Bosnian","ro_MD":"Romanian (Moldova)","en_CA":"English (Canadian)","en_PH":"English (Phillipines)","en_IN":"English (Indian)","en_MY":"English (Malaysian)","en_AU":"English (Australian)","sh":"Serbian (Latin)","sr":"Serbian (Cyrillic)","ka":"Georgian","fr_CA":"French (Canadian)","sl":"Slovene","hr":"Croatian","pt_PT":"Portuguese (European)","sk":"Slovak","ar":"Arabic","en_GB":"English (UK)","bg":"Bulgarian","el":"Greek","iw":"Hebrew","uk":"Ukrainian","vi":"Vietnamese","ro":"Romanian","in":"Indonesian","tr":"Turkish","cs":"Czech","pl":"Polish","hu":"Hungarian","no":"Norwegian","es_MX":"Spanish (Mexico)","ru":"Russian","fi":"Finnish","th":"Thai","da":"Danish","nl_NL":"Dutch","pt_BR":"Portuguese (Brazil)","zh_CN":"Chinese (Simplified)","zh_TW":"Chinese (Traditional)","ko":"Korean","sv":"Swedish","ja":"Japanese","it":"Italian","fr":"French","es":"Spanish","de":"German","en_US":"English"}
```

Although there few codes which are like "iT","FR" etc but What I can take a conclusion is I can suggest a solution such that external system can update there database comparing codes returned from Salesforce side.

Answer (score 3):

English is not the only language which displays this behavior. In fact, Spanish also has a locale-specific value (for Mexico). You can see all the available values and their labels using this script:

```
Map<String, String> languageCodes = new Map<String, String>();
for (PicklistEntry entry : User.LanguageLocaleKey.getDescribe().getPicklistValues())
    languageCodes.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getLabel());
system.debug(JSON.serialize(languageCodes));
```

Which will output:

> ```
> {
>     "no": "Norwegian",
>     "es_MX": "Spanish (Mexico)",
>     "ru": "Russian",
>     "fi": "Finnish",
>     "th": "Thai",
>     "da": "Danish",
>     "nl_NL": "Dutch",
>     "pt_BR": "Portuguese (Brazil)",
>     "zh_CN": "Chinese (Simplified)",
>     "zh_TW": "Chinese (Traditional)",
>     "ko": "Korean",
>     "sv": "Swedish",
>     "ja": "Japanese",
>     "it": "Italian",
>     "fr": "French",
>     "es": "Spanish",
>     "de": "German",
>     "en_US": "English"
> }
> ```

Comment: but why all languages doesn't follow this kind of pattern?

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande Because that's how they built the picklist. Perhaps the development team intends to support British English in the future. Why questions are notoriously difficult to answer and I'm not certain it is possible for anyone but those who made the design decisions to actually give you a concrete answer here.

Comment: but isn't it make sense to have code designed according to standard followed across all the systems? this can be topic of discussion though!